# C# Linq Group by with Distinct not working

Tags: c#, linq

I've reviewed numerous articles here on SO about how to group by using a LINQ statement on a list object but the following code fails to group anything even though all the variables have the exact same values. Could someone please tell me why this might not be working? Does it have something to do with LINQ deferred execution? I've tried a sample where I included a second select statement which did not help. I'm passing in a `list<MyClass>` object which has two identical items and one that is not, so when this statement executes I should receive back only two items.

Actual values in the code:

```
   Type = 1, Capacity = 50, Goal = "Teach algebra", 
   Attachments = "", Hours = 1, TypeDesignation = 3, 
   TypeControl = 1, Supplies = 0 

   TypeControl and Supplies are both objects themselves. Supplies is empty.
   TypeControl contains Id = 23, Text = "Math", Active = 1

        var test = newclass.GroupBy(n => new 
        {
            n.Type,
            n.Capacity,
            n.Goal,
            n.Attachments,
            n.Hours,
            n.TypeDesignation,
            n.TypeControl,
            n.Supplies

        }).Distinct().Select(n => new MyClass()
        {
            Type = n.Key.Type,
            Capacity = n.Key.Capacity,
            Goal = n.Key.Goal ,
            Attachments = n.Key.Attachments,
            Hours = n.Key.Hours ,
            TypeDesignation = n.Key.TypeDesignation,
            TypeControl = n.Key.TypeControl,
            Supplies = n.Key.Supplies
        });
```

Comment: Why do you use `Distinct` at all after `GroupBy`? Each group is unique by the key anyway.

Comment: @TimSchmelter One of the posts I read recommended adding the Distinct so it's one of the things that I've tried. When you say each group is unique by the Key you are referring to the Key inside the select statement? I removed the Distinct and retested but I still receive three items back.

Comment: @ElaineK A `GroupBy` will result in an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>` where each `IGrouping<TKey, TSource>` has a key based on the lambda you supplied to `GroupBy`.  That key will be unique and thus each `IGrouping<TKey, TSource>` is unique and `Distinct` will have no effect.

Comment: @elaine: yes, `GroupBy` returns groups, your anonymous type is the key for the group which means that every group's combination of `Type,Capacity,Goal,Attachments,Hours,TypeDesignation,TypeControl,Supplies` is unique.

Comment: I think you just want to select the keys?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question was that the all the objects inside were, in fact, not equal, in that I had a sub-object that during the group by one object was read as being null while the other was reading as being 0 so they never could group together but when I looked at them with intellisense they always both said null. I resolved the issue by looping through my list and using a comparer method to drill down into the sub-objects and find the differences.

```
        VerifyDuplicates duplicates = new VerifyDuplicates();

        List<MyClass> newClass = new List<MyClass>(); 

        classes = classes.OrderBy(s => s.Type).ToList();
        List<int> idsToDelete = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < classes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i + 1 < classes.Count)
            {
                var x = duplicates.Compare(classes[i], classes[i + 1]);
                if (x == 1)
                    idsToDelete.Add(classes[i+1].Id);
            }
        }
        newClass = classes.Where(n => !idsToDelete.Contains(n.Id)).Select(n => n).ToList();

    public class VerifyDuplicates : Comparer<MyClass>
    {
        public override int Compare(MyClass x, MyClass y)
        {
            int p = 0;

            if(x != null && y != null)
            { 
                if(x.Type.Equals(y.Type)) { p += 1; }
                if(x.Attachments.Equals(y.Attachments)) { p += 1; }
                if(x.Capacity.Equals(y.Capacity)) { p += 1; }
                if(x.Goal.Equals(y.Goal)) { p += 1; }
                if(x.Hours.Equals(y.Hours)) { p += 1; }
                if(x.TypeDesignation.Equals(y.TypeDesignation)) { p += 1; }
                if(x.TypeControl != null && y.TypeControl != null)
                    if(x.TypeControl[0].Equals(y.TypeControl[0])) { p += 1; }
                if(x.Supplies != null && y.Supplies!= null)
                    if (x.Supplies.Equals(y.Supplies)) { p += 1; }

                return p;
            }
      }
  }
```